# AWS CDK access Denied when trying to create connection AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have written a CDK code for creating a connection but I am getting an error while creating:

`User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:root is not authorized to perform: glue:CreateConnection on resource: arn:aws:glue:us-east-2:Connectionnew:catalog (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: a8702efb-4467-4ffb-8fe0-18468f336299)`

Below is my simple Code:

```
glue_connection = glue.CfnConnection(self, "Connectionnew",
   catalog_id = "Connectionnew",
   connection_input = {
       "connectionType":"JDBC",
       "Name":"JDBCConnection",
       "connectionProperties": {
           "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "jdbc:redshift://non-prod-royalties2.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:xxx/xxxxx",
           "USERNAME":"xxxxxx",
           "Password":"xxxxxxxx"
       }
   }
)
```

Please help me with this

Comment: I down-voted your question because: (1) your markdown formatting was incorrect, which made it extremely difficult to read. SO provides a clear preview of your question before you submit. Please make sure to use it. (2) it appears as if you didn't take the time to research the issue on your own before submitting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Being that you are using the root account ([which is not advisable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#lock-away-credentials)), it's not an issue of your active AWS user having the incorrect permissions.

Likely, the connection details you are providing are incorrect. The username/password might be correct but the formatting of the JSON is questionable. I'd check to see if the JDBC keys are case-sensitive because that could be your issue.

Comment: According to my research i found that even my root does not have access to create any kind of glue connection,WHile using access keys this issue is coming.

Comment: what isthe exact permission on root it is looking for as i am using my root access keys to deployment of AWS CDK

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this issue resolved but putting the AWS accountnumber as below:

`glue_connection = glue.CfnConnection(self, "Connectionnew", catalog_id = "AWSAccountNumber", connection_input = { "connectionType": "JDBC", "Name": "JDBCConnection", "connectionProperties": { "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "jdbcredshiftlink", "USERNAME": "xxxxxx", "PASSWORD": "xxxxxxxx" } } )`